# How can I Split a Long Text without spaces and add it to excel rows with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So i have extracted some rows from an excel sheet and stored them in a variable
now when i try to paste them in new excel sheet it gets pasted in only one cell
so i try to split them with 18 digit filter but it gives \n at the end of charater and also same error that it gets pasted in one cell
here is the output

```
['1Z69663R0303053717', '\n1Z69663R030387219', '0\n1Z69663R03110928', '02\n1Z69663R0339944', '803\n1Z69663R031781', '7027\n1Z69663R03370', '74426\n1Z69663R0311', '585244\n1Z69663R032', '0888909\n1Z69663R03', '25360513\n1Z69663R0', '315453683\n1Z69663R', '4239120094\n1Z69663', 'R0318776276\n1Z6966', '3R0339843341\n1Z696', '63R0315883629\n1Z69', '663R0324813133\n1Z6', '9663R0321691495']
```

i want to add this data set to excel file in new cell of each  and get rid of \n

Comment: can you share the code so we know what you are trying to do? Also, its easy to remove `\n` from the list. All you need to do is use string.replace()

Comment: Thanks  but somehow i have managed to remove \n